# Cloud Foundry Turbine Stream Unable to connect to Command Metric Stream

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud, turbine

I have set up a Turbine Application and everything runs fine when I run it locally.

The application comes up in Cloud Foundry, however, the Hystrix Dashboard can't seem to connect to :8989/turbine.stream

Unable to connect to Command Metric Stream.

In Cloud Foundry, do I need to expose a service for /turbine.stream?

The apps are all connected to rabbitmq.

The Turbine Application is configured in yml:

```
server:
  port: ${PORT:8990}

turbine:
  stream:
    port: 8989
```

Here is the app

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTurbineStream
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class TurbineApplication {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        new SpringApplicationBuilder( TurbineApplication.class ).run( args );

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was the solution. My configuration was wrong.

```
server:
  port: ${PORT:8989}

management:
  port: 8990

---
spring:
  profiles: cloud

management:
  port: -1
```

It looks like I needed to shut off the management port, set it to -1, so that only the Rx Netty server will start on 8080.